# assign key as list index+1 to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I want to convert them to dictionary but the key should be tuples index in the list+1

So if my list of tuple is

```
[(113, 254), (163, 253), (230, 252), (197, 251), (184, 249), (211, 247), (151, 245), (242, 243), (173, 242), (191, 238)]
```

I want to create a dictionary of the list of tuples having key as tuples index in the list + 1. Similar to

```
{1:(113, 254), 2:(163, 253), 3:(230, 252), 4:(197, 251), 5:(184, 249), 6:(211,247), 7:(151, 245), 8:(242, 243), 9:(173, 242), 10:(191, 238)}
```

Comment: Typically you'd use a list rather than a dict if you want to look things up by sequentially-increasing indices. It's more efficient (no hashing!) and intuitive to code, but in any case I don't see any question or code attempt here so I'll vote to close as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> x = [(113, 254), (163, 253), (230, 252), (197, 251), (184, 249), (211, 247), (151, 245), (242, 243), (173, 242), (191, 238)]
>>> dict(enumerate(x, start=1))
{1: (113, 254), 2: (163, 253), 3: (230, 252), 4: (197, 251), 5: (184, 249), 6: (211, 247), 7: (151, 245), 8: (242, 243), 9: (173, 242), 10: (191, 238)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
lst = [(113, 254), (163, 253), (230, 252), (197, 251), (184, 249), (211, 247), (151, 245), (242, 243), (173, 242), (191, 238)]

dictionary = {}

key = 1

for item in lst:
    dictionary[key] = item
    key+=1

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{1: (113, 254), 2: (163, 253), 3: (230, 252), 4: (197, 251), 5: (184, 249), 6: (211, 247), 7: (151, 245), 8: (242, 243), 9: (173, 242), 10: (191, 238)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
a = [(113, 254), (163, 253), (230, 252), (197, 251),\
 (184, 249), (211, 247), (151, 245), (242, 243), (173, 242), (191, 238)]
d = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    d[(i + 1)] = a[i]
```

produces

```
{1: (113, 254),
 2: (163, 253),
 3: (230, 252),
 4: (197, 251),
 5: (184, 249),
 6: (211, 247),
 7: (151, 245),
 8: (242, 243),
 9: (173, 242),
 10: (191, 238)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions in dictionaries. To learn more: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
tuple_list = [(113, 254), (163, 253), (230, 252), (197, 251), (184, 249), (211, 247), (151, 245), (242, 243), (173, 242), (191, 238)]
{i:tup for i, tup in enumerate(tuple_list, start=1)}
```

Output will be:

```
{1: (113, 254), 2: (163, 253), 3: (230, 252), 4: (197, 251), 5: (184, 249), 6: (211, 247), 7: (151, 245), 8: (242, 243), 9: (173, 242), 10: (191, 238)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use range starting from 1 and assign values.

```py
lst = [(113, 254), (163, 253), (230, 252), (197, 251), (184, 249), (211, 247), (151, 245), (242, 243), (173, 242), (191, 238)]

dic = {}
for i in range(1,(len(lst) + 1)):
    dic[i] = lst[i-1]
    
dic
```

```
{1: (113, 254),
 2: (163, 253),
 3: (230, 252),
 4: (197, 251),
 5: (184, 249),
 6: (211, 247),
 7: (151, 245),
 8: (242, 243),
 9: (173, 242),
 10: (191, 238)}
```